# I'm having difficulty inserting a series of different requests into my code

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

Hello I'm very new to Java and all its wonders. I'm thoroughly confused when it comes to while-loops and for-loops. I'm having difficulty making my code print an average of an n amount of user inputs for real numbers only, then calculating the average and getting the high and low value for the inputs used. and also if user types "end" cease and calculate....I've only been using java maybe 2 weeks please bare with my noobiness I'm trying to learn but loops are hard to get my hear around... here's my code so far.

```
int inputNumber = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a few real numbers"));
//number entered by user
while (inputNumber !=0) {//numbers entered
    sum += inputNumber;
    count++;//adds one to count for every number entered

    if (count == 7){
        System.out.println("thats enough numbers enter end");
        //stops excess of seven numbers prompts type end to finish
    }
    else {
        average = ((double)sum) / count;//gets average double the numbers divided by number of numbers
        System.out.println("average:"+ average); //displays average

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average is "       +average + "and the number of numbers entered is " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"Enter a few real numbers"` is outside the loop so it runs only once. On the other hand `"The average is " ` is inside the loop - guess you want it outside the loop, after all numbers were input.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the no of inputs outside the loop from the user, iterate total number of times to get the input and sum, calculate average once sum is calculated

```
    int total = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter total number of inputs "));
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter input number "));
    }
    average = sum / total;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average is " + average + "and the number of numbers entered is " + total);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write one, hope it helps. I am also new to Java, as well.

```
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int inputNumber2 = 0;
    //number entered by user
    while (inputNumber2 == 0) {//numbers entered

        int inputNumber = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a few real numbers"));
        sum += inputNumber;
        count++;//adds one to count for every number entered

        if (count == 7) {
           // System.out.println("thats enough numbers enter end");
            //stops excess of seven numbers prompts type end to finish
            String text3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Thats enough numbers enter end");
            break;
        } else {
            average = ((double) sum) / ((double)count);//gets average double the numbers divided by number of numbers
            System.out.println("average:" + average); //displays average

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average is " + average + "and the number of numbers entered is " + count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for helping :)